# Why isn't my foreach loop printing the correct output?

Tags: c#, foreach, user-input

I made a foreach loop that would take a user's input and subtract two numbers on the same line, I was hoping it would print out the difference between any two numbers, but it didn't. Instead, when I ran the code and entered the numbers, it printed a different answer which didn't make sense to me. I'm kind of a bit new to c# so I'm just experimenting with things, but if anyone knows what's wrong with my code please help me figure out what's wrong with it. Thanks!

```
using System;
                
public class Program 
{
    string sequence;
    double answer;
    
    public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<<SUBTRACTION CODE>>");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sequence of numbers and an operator to get subtracted answer ");
        Console.WriteLine("Eg: 10-5");
        sequence = Console.ReadLine();
    
        foreach (var operation in sequence.Split('-'))
            {
               answer -= double.Parse(operation); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine(answer);
            Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

Comment: well, what **do** you get and what do you **except instead**?

Comment: your answer will initially be zero. So when you do `answer -=` your subtract the right-hand-site from zero, which will result in a negative outcome. I suppose you need to assign the first operat to your `answer`.

Comment: 0 - 10 = -10. Next time -10 - -5. You can work it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want 5 rather than -15?

You need to initialise the value of answer with the first number rather than subtract everything from a starting point of zero.

```
bool init;
string sequence;
double answer;

public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("<<SUBTRACTION CODE>>");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a sequence of numbers and an operator to get subtracted answer ");
    Console.WriteLine("Eg: 10-5");
    sequence = Console.ReadLine();

    foreach (var operation in sequence.Split('-'))
        {
           if (!init) {
               answer = double.Parse(operation); 
               init = true;
           }
           else
               answer -= double.Parse(operation); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I agree, if it was proper code I would never use abbreviations for that very reason.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, I was stuck all day trying to figure it out, I probably got to do a lot more reading and practice. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

your `answer` will initially be `0`. So when you do `answer -=` you subtract the right-hand-site (e.g. `5`) from zero, which will result in a negative outcome. I suppose you need to assign the first operat to your `answer`:

```
using System;
                
public class Program 
{
    string sequence;
    double answer;
    
    public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<<SUBTRACTION CODE>>");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sequence of numbers and an operator to get subtracted answer ");
        Console.WriteLine("Eg: 10-5");
        sequence = Console.ReadLine();
        var parts = sequence.Split('-');

        answer = parts[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
           answer -= double.Parse(parts[i]); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 
}
```

Of course you should check if there are at least two elements within `parts`.